# what are the differences of various FB login methods?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, fbconnect

There are three different login methods in iOS:

1. Login via web pop-up
2. Login via Safari
3. Login via Native App

and one more in iOS 6 - login via native pop-up controller using iOS 6 Facebook credentials.

In my case, I'm using FB comments plugin inside UIWebView and I'd like to allow user to leave comments there. For that I'm using FB login via web pop-up. Using other methods lead to the two different results:

1. FB comments plugin not loading at all
2. FB comments plugin loaded, but user is still unauthorized (login via Safari)

Whereas I have no idea, how to deal with the first one, the second one happens I think because cookies (or FB credentials) are stored in safari, but not in my App, which is required for comments plugin to understand that the user has logged in.

In this case, I'm wondering - when and where should we use each of the FB login approaches? 
And what should I use in my case?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the plugin you used? It sounds to me like it's a 3rd-party plugin using deprecated APIs of the facebook SDK.
Generally, you should only ask the SDK for a session and let it handle the rest (which includes choosing the method). You can then continue to do what you intended with the session returned.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Parse to handle social account management.  It's super easy to integrate with your code and free for your purposes.  [Take a look](https://parse.com/products/social).  Just sign up to Parse, Create an App and follow the easy quickstart guide.  They also have great documentation and forums to help you out.